# Pandas create new column with values from other columns, selected based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe that looks like a bit like this example. For some reasons, the raw data has the value replicated across.

```
  Node Node 1 Value Node 2 Value Node 3 Value
0    1            A            B            C
1    2            A            B            C
2    3            A            B            C
```

I want to transform it to look like this:

```
  Node Value
0    1     A
1    2     B
2    3     C
```

This iterrows code works as intended but it is very slow for my data (48 nodes with ~20,000 values).

I feel like there must be a faster way, perhaps with `apply` but I can't figure it out.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Node": ["1", "2", "3"],
                   "Node 1 Value": ["A","A","A"],
                   "Node 2 Value": ["B","B","B"],
                   "Node 3 Value": ["C","C","C"]})

print(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, 'Value'] = row["Node {} Value".format(row['Node'])]

print(df[['Node','Value']])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) and then [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
a = df.lookup(df.index, "Node " + df.Node.astype(str) + " Value")

df = df[['Node']].assign(Value = a)
print (df)
   Node Value
0     1     A
1     2     B
2     3     C
```

EDIT: If some values missing you can extract this values by [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) for dictionary with default value, e.g. `np.nan` and add to DataFrame before `lookup`:

```
print (df)
   Node Node 1 Value Node 2 Value Node 3 Value
0     1            A            B            C
1     2            A            B            C
3     5            A            B            C

s = "Node " + df.Node.astype(str) + " Value"
new = dict.fromkeys(np.setdiff1d(s, df.columns), np.nan)
print (new)
{'Node 5 Value': nan}

print (df.assign(**new))
   Node Node 1 Value Node 2 Value Node 3 Value  Node 5 Value
0     1            A            B            C           NaN
1     2            A            B            C           NaN
3     5            A            B            C           NaN

a = df.assign(**new).lookup(df.index, s)
print (a)
['A' 'B' nan]

df = df[['Node']].assign(Value = a)
print (df)
   Node Value
0     1     A
1     2     B
3     5   NaN
```

Another idea with [definition of lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
def f(row, col):
    try:
        return df.at[row, col]
    except:
        return np.nan

s = "Node " + df.Node.astype(str) + " Value"
a = [f(row, col) for row, col in zip(df.index, s)]

df = df[['Node']].assign(Value = a)
print (df)
   Node Value
0     1     A
1     2     B
3     5   NaN
```

And solution with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
s = "Node " + df.Node.astype(str) + " Value"
b = (df.assign(Node = s)
        .reset_index()
        .melt(['index','Node'], value_name='Value')
        .query('Node == variable').set_index('index')['Value'])


df = df[['Node']].join(b)
print (df)
   Node Value
0     1     A
1     2     B
3     5   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for the example but in my real case, I get `KeyError: 'One or more column labels was not found'` Is there an elegant way to skip missing values?

Comment: @George - Added solution for this.

Comment: 1 min 36s to 17s.

Comment: @George - I have one ide, give me a sec.

Comment: @George - Not sure if faster, but added another solution.

Comment: About 1s faster the new way. Thanks again!